# Pages cost money now?

Tags: backup, apple-id, mac-appstore, pages

I had to clear my MacBook air as i had created an account with a password I couldn't remember, and I had an old apple ID linked to it that couldn't be logged out of unless I remembered the laptop password. So I cleared the MacBook, completely reset it up , and logged into my new, current apple ID. Now it says pages and numbers cost €19.99 ? I could probably live without these, but I had pages saved to my initial pages iCloud account.. so i really need it back.. Anyone know how I can re download these apps for free, and then will I be able to get the previous pages back? Any help much appreciated. - I also have completely updated the laptop so it has sierra, and all software is update.And I have tried logging out and logging back in in the different apple Ids . I don't think I made a computer back up.. Everything is on my initial apple Id.

Comment: see the edit to my previous answer. Looks like Apple has now made this free.

Answer (score 1):

Macs purchased before 2013 do not get iWork for free since before that point it was not included with the purchase of the computer.

As a workaround some users of older macs install the [iWork '09 Trial](http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/iWork/Trial/2Z693-6764.01022009.awq23/iWork09Trial.dmg)

Edit: Looks like Apple today decided to give this away for free even on older hardware. [See here.](https://arstechnica.com/apple/2017/04/iwork-and-ilife-apps-are-now-free-for-old-and-new-mac-and-ios-users/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apple.com/creativity-apps/mac/up-to-date/

Apple has made Pages, Numbers, and Keynote free for qualifying Mac computers purchased on or after October 1, 2013.

Check your purchase list in the app store and see if Pages, Numbers, and Keynote are on it. If it is you can download it for free, don't worry about the price tag. If it isn't you can try to apply for the up-to-date program I linked above.